Google maps advanced marker with draggable option has erratic positions when dragging it
I'm using the latest version of their TS library and having a custom SVG as a marker. It's on top of React. When I get into full screen mode to place the marker, it moves erratically when starting to drag it. This is problematic because it causes a pretty bad UX. One important detail is that even using their default marker it'll also have this odd behavior.

The code is as follow (not the most beautiful but working)
export const MapAPI = ({ geolocation, setGeolocation }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
      center: { lat: geolocation.latitude, lng: geolocation.longitude },
      zoom: DEFAULT_ZOOM,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      rotateControl: false,
      mapId: MAP_ID,
    };

    // we need to use async for the library load
    (async () => {
      preventMapsStyleSpread();

      const { Map } = (await google.maps.importLibrary(
        "maps"
      )) as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
      const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = (await google.maps.importLibrary(
        "marker"
      )) as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;

      const map = new Map(ref.current as HTMLElement, mapOptions);

      const draggableMarker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
        map,
        content: mapPinSvg,
        position: { lat: geolocation.latitude, lng: geolocation.longitude },
        gmpDraggable: true,
      });

      draggableMarker.addListener("dragend", () => {
        const position = draggableMarker.position as google.maps.LatLng;
        setGeolocation({
          latitude: position.lat,
          longitude: position.lng,
          // we keep the same accuracy
          accuracy: geolocation.accuracy,
        });
      });
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        height: "300px",
        width: "100%",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto",
      }}
    />
  );
};

function preventMapsStyleSpread() {
  // This is to prevent Google Maps from loading Roboto
  // And fucking up the boldness of the whole application
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  const insertBefore = head.insertBefore;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {
    if (
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore
      newElement.href &&
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore
      newElement.href.indexOf("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto") > -1
    ) {
      console.info("Prevented Roboto from loading!");
      return;
    }

    insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
  };
}

Is it really a bug or am I missing something?

Can you also show the implementation of your preventMapsStyleSpread function? Coz I've attempted to replicate the draggable marker functionality in React and dragging works seamlessly just as shown in the official doc. However, haven't experimented with using custom svg for the markers yet. To help you better, could you also provide a reproducible example, preferably on CodeSandbox?

Oh yeah sorry for that I forgot a piece, Just updated the question

FYI it's just an unrelated hack because the map was kinda screwing the design around it, I found this way of preventing it from Stackoverflow I think because I'm not the only one facing that

Just randomly looking back at my question, I couldn't solve the problem and disabled the full screen in my case. There's definitely a bug in there but I couldn't find what it was.

Anyone find a solution to this, I am having the same problem with a vue3 plugin. With an image as the content and only in fullscreen does it get offset.

Looks like there is a tracker. Please upvote here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/339479347 so we can get it fixed. It's been way too long.
